# PHP - Regular Expression to Remove Single Quotes From Beginning and End of a String

Tags: php

I have a string variable like `$string = "'dj12JKmi3433Kl09'"`. How to remove the single quotes `'` from the beginning and end of the string using a `preg_replace` function? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need a regex for this; you can just use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim), as in `trim($string, "'")`.

If you really want a regex for some reason, this one would do it:

```
/^'+|'+$/
```

Just replace with `''`.

Comment: Interesting; I didn't know that about `trim()`, *till now*.